# Variance of independent events

Tags: probability, solution-verification

The probability that the light bulb is working is $0.8$. There are $10$ such lamps in the room. Find the variance of working lamps in the room.

Here is my solution:

$D[X] = M[X^2]-(M[X])^2= \sum_i^{N=10} p_i \cdot x_i^2-(\sum_i^{N=10} p_i \cdot x_i)^2=100\cdot0.8\cdot1^2-(10\cdot0.8\cdot1)^2=80-64=16$

I have two questions.

Firstly, is it correct to calculate the square of a random variable in this way (the event is discrete - the lamp either works or it doesn't)? I suppose that $x_i$ is equal to 1. Can this be written somehow more mathematically correctly?

Secondly, am I correct in assuming that this variance tells us that if we could repeat the experiment with turning on the lamps in the room a large number of times, then the deviation of the number of lamps on from the average (the average is 8) would most often be $4$ (as $\sqrt{ D[X]}$)? But the deviation is assumed in both directions, including the larger one, but $8+4=12$, but we initially have 10 lamps in the room. How then to interpret the variance of such independent events?

Comment: The variance should be 1.6

Comment: Why did you divide the total variance by 10? The variance in the number of working lamps is asked in the task.

Comment: I multiplied with 10. The number of working lamps has a binomial distribution with mean n*p=8 and variance n*p*(1-p)=1.6.